# Mean Value Theorem - one step to go

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

## Good evening!

I should prove the following inequality with the Mean-Value-Theorem:

$$\cos (x) ≥ 1- \dfrac{x^2}{2} $$
∀x∈R

I set up a new function called $g(x)$
$$ \cos(x) -1+\dfrac{x^2}{2} ≥ 0$$
$$ g(x) = \cos(x) -1+\dfrac{x^2}{2} ≥0 \\ g(0) = 0$$

Now I checked all $x>0$: $[0,x]$

$$g'(\xi) = \dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} ≥ 0$$
$$ \dfrac{\cos(x)-1 + \dfrac{x^2}{2}}{x} \geq 0 $$
$$ \cos(x) \geq 1- \dfrac{x^2}{2} $$

*Got a stuck at the following point:*

**I don't know** what I should do in the next step to check for x<0: [x,0]

so x is negativ -> signs will change

**???**
$$g'(\xi) = \dfrac{g(0)-g(x)}{0-x} ≥ 0$$
$$ \dfrac{-(\cos(x)-1 + \dfrac{x^2}{2})}{-x} \geq 0 $$
$$ \dfrac{\cos(x)-1 + \dfrac{x^2}{2}}{x} \geq 0 $$
Now multiplication with x (which is lower 0)
$$ \cos(x) \leq 1- \dfrac{x^2}{2} $$

So at this point I guess I am wrong and so I don't know what I have to do instead to fix this prove.
Thanks you all for answers! Opendminded for tricks!

Comment: You should have set $g(x)=\cos x-1 \color{red}+\dfrac{x^2}2$.

Comment: Thanks, edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Let

$$g(x) = \cos(x) -1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}\implies g'(x)=x-\sin x\ge 0 \quad x\ge 0$$

then use

$$\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=g'(\xi) \quad \xi\in(0,x)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Got it at that point! But what should I do with x < 0?

Comment: @JohnM You are welcome! Can you proceed and conclude form here?

Comment: I can conclude it from here. I got the prove now for all x > 0. Could you help me once again at the point to prove it for all x < 0? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @JohnM Since we are considering at the RHS $x(x-\sin x)$ and $x-sinx \le 0$ for $x\le 0$, the result follows. More simply just note that $g(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: Ohh, thank you! So I can refer to the property of the function? So if I take an x < 0, the result will be automatically positive! I see! Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @JohnM Yes of course, since the function is even we can refer wlog to the case $x\ge 0$. Or if you prefer, we can also prove at the same way for $x\le 0$.